# Javascript multi-step form not going to next step

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was making a multi step sign up form but the 'next button' did not work.

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/champforevaa/bcyy74n9/  and here is the code:

Signup.html:

```
<!-- multistep form -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Signup.css">
    <script src="./Signup.js"></script>
<form id="msform">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
        <li>Social Profiles</li>
        <li>Personal Details</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
        <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
        <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
        <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
        <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
        <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
        <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery easing plugin -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Signup.js:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- jQuery easing plugin -->
  <script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
      /* 
  Orginal Page: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-multi-step-form-with-progress-bar 

  */
  //jQuery time
  var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
  var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
  var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

  $(".next").click(function() {
      if(animating) return false;
      animating = true;

      current_fs = $(this).parent();
      next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

      //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
      $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

      //show the next fieldset
      next_fs.show(); 
      //hide the current fieldset with style
      current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
          step: function(now, mx) {
              //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
              //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
              scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
              //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
              left = (now * 50)+"%";
              //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
              opacity = 1 - now;
              current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
              next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
          }, 
          duration: 800, 
          complete: function() {
              current_fs.hide();
              animating = false;
          }, 
          //this comes from the custom easing plugin
          easing: 'easeInOutBack'
      });
  });

  $(".previous").click(function() {
      if(animating) return false;
      animating = true;

      current_fs = $(this).parent();
      previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

      //de-activate current step on progressbar
      $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

      //show the previous fieldset
      previous_fs.show(); 
      //hide the current fieldset with style
      current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
          step: function(now, mx) {
              //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
              //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
              scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
              //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
              left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
              //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
              opacity = 1 - now;
              current_fs.css({'left': left});
              previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
          }, 
          duration: 800, 
          complete: function(){
              current_fs.hide();
              animating = false;
          }, 
          //this comes from the custom easing plugin
          easing: 'easeInOutBack'
      });
  });

  $(".submit").click(function(){
      return false;
  })
```

As seen in the jsFiddle, the next button does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your `code` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w39mpdjv/3/) the problem was in the `JS` panel you should just type `javascript` without `<script>` tags so, to `include` your libraries

> i used the option "external resources" (at the panel in the left
>   side), and now works, regards!

Comment: Please check the link: http://jsfiddle.net/w39mpdjv/3/ is your same code i just used the option "external resources"

Comment: Is there any example of steppers that use angular/pure css3

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not including `jquery.js` files and `jquery.easing` js files properly because you are trying to get it from `http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js` and `http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js` which is not a CDN [Content Delivery Network] So what changes you can make is remove both the script reference from `html` and `js`  and add the below references as src for the script.

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js 
^^^^//for easing

//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js
 ^^ for jquery.js
```

Everything else is good then.
**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/bcyy74n9/4/)**

Comment: Still not working. It stays stuck. Next doesnt work at all

Comment: check the console for any errors! Open page in browser right click and select inspect element and go to console tab and see what error you see?